# TToolButton Text Alignment

Tags: delphi, properties, toolbar, c++builder

As I understand there is no properly available to align text in `TToolButton` like `Layout` property for `TSpeedButton`. Is there a way to align text on the right somehow (equivalent of `blGlyphLeft` value in `Layout` property of a `TSpeedButton`)?

I already have a specialized function for adding button - `AddButtonToToolBar()` with obvious purpose. Is there a way to add something to it to align button text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can align text to the right of the image by setting the `TBSTYLE_LIST` style, according to the link above. In Delphi's `TToolBar`, you set this style by setting the [`TToolBar.List`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TToolBar.List) property to `True`.

> Aligns captions on the right and images on the left in tool buttons.
>
> When List is false, tool buttons (TToolButton) appear in the toolbar with their images (if any) centered and their captions (if visible) underneath. Setting List to true aligns captions to the right and images to the left.

Comment: What about List-style Toolbars from the same link - `TBSTYLE_LIST`?

Comment: Found the property... it is totally non-logical named "List".

Comment: @Coder12345: Found it and posted an edit about the same time you posted your last comment. Thanks for making me look at this in more detail. I found functionality I'd missed, and then figured out it's actually already implemented in TToolBar itself. Answer basically rewritten from scratch as a result.

Comment: Found another property not so well known - "Customizable" which opens customize dialog. I never knew it was always there and assumed I'd have to code this myself. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: :-) That one I knew about, at least.